# Yesterday's performance / performance of / performance for

Tags: possessives

> He is a fast bowler of repute, but his **yesterday's performance** wasn't up to the mark.

Which is the correct option to replace the bold part in above sentence ?

A) performance of yesterday

B) performance for yesterday

I know *yesterday's performance* is too correct in spoken English but I am asking in context of formal English which option from A and B is correct to use here ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

> He is a fast bowler of repute, but his **performance yesterday** wasn't up to the mark.

No preposition is used with *yesterday*.

Also, using *repute* is dated at best. I would use:

> He **has a reputation** as a fast bowler, but his performance yesterday wasn't up to the mark.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways that will work.

The most standard way, is to use yesterday separately - marking what time frame you're talking about his bad performance in:

> He is a fast bowler, but yesterday, his performance wasn't up to the mark.
>
> He is a fast bowler, but his performance wasn't up to the mark yesterday.
>
> He is a fast bowler, but his performance, yesterday, wasn't up to the mark.

Note that the the third example may seem similar to what you have written - but it's important to note that "performance yesterday" doesn't work well by itself. It is a sentence talking about his performance, with the qualifying time frame in parenthesis.

---

Alternatively, you can talk about *yesterday's performance*. This is more commonly used when talking about an event, such as a match, that has just happened.

> He is [normally] a fast bowler, but yesterday's performance wasn't up the mark.

This kind of phrasing is most commonly used when talking about a sporting event that has just happened - and when trying to bring conversation onto the subject of the previous day's match. It moves the focus away from him normally being a fast bowler, and onto the fact that yesterday he wasn't.